# How to Temporarily Open a Read-only file as Writeable?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, read-only

I have an Excel file which I set on Read-Only mode to make sure I don't inadvertently change it's contents.  However, sometimes I do need to open this file to make changes to it. Is it possible to open this file temporarily in write-mode so I can edit it?

Currently I have to always go to the file properties to disable Read-Only and sometimes I forget to turn it back on after I'm done with the editing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One workaround you can do instead of putting the actual files as read only, you can "Lock" the worksheet. And only put in your password to "Unlock" and Edit the content. And at the end of the day just have to protect worksheet again.

This is still the same step as what you are doing now, but at least the Protect / Unprotect sheet are all within Excel. And also you can protect sheet without password.

Hope this helps.